# ZSH npm/node/nvm command not found after installing OhMyZSH

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zsh

After installing OhMyZSH on my Linux machine, previously installed nvm, node and npm are not found. Thanks for the help.

This command "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh" allows me to make it work, however when I restart terminal or open new tab terminal says that commands are not found... Config '~/.zshrc' file:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
 export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
 export ZSH="/home/jurr/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Comment: This can actually happen with a lot of things after installing OhMyZSH, depending on what you had on your `.zshrc`. Just look for a `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`

Comment: I'm new to omz, BUT it looks like the 'standard' way to install stuff is to use plugins. Any reason the answer from @incodenito shouldn't be the accepted answer? I've searched for documentation that breaks out this approach, and am surprised not to find it....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Added this line to ./zshrc file. Working great.
Original source: https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Comment: This solution worked perfect for macOS Big Sur

Comment: This one works man!!!!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem after exiting the terminal the nvm command was not found. So to fix this you have to add

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  
# This loads nvm bash_completion
```

this line of code on your .zshrc file
to do that type `vim ~/.zshrc` than add the following lines in the bottom and to save the file click ctrl than press `:wq!` to save file in vim you can also use nano

Answer (score 2):

Adding plugin nvm, just edit .zshrc file

> plugins=(git nvm)

Close terminal, reopen terminal, hope this solves the problem on your machine too.

Found this solution from this blog post https://www.brijumaquio.com/node-not-working-after-installing-zsh-ubuntu18

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Details in Gist.

```
  1. Installed nodeJs via nvm using Git Bash
  2. Installed hyper terminal & WSL
  3. Installed Ubuntu (windows Store) & configured zsh shell. 
  4. Faced the command not found all over in the zsh shell
  5. The same commands are working nicely in the bash shell
```

Tried sourcing the (node, nvm, npm ) paths in the .**zshrc** and **.profile** file &
modified the System & Environment Variables in Windows. None of these steps helped me to resolve the issue.

I think the issue is zsh and bash terminals treat things differently. When Installed in bash terminal the default location for the nodeJs in windows will be set to

```
C:\Users\Program Files\nodejs
```

The above one is symlinked to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm`

No matter how much I tried to alias these things in zsh, only node and nvm are working with aliases. npm is failing to locate the necessary lib files.

## The only solution that worked for me is **Re-installing node in zsh terminal**

1. Removed the node versions installed via nvm in Bash terminal.
2. Removed the nvm in windows via control Panel
3. Installed the nvm in the zsh shell
4. Installed the node latest LTS version from which npm is also installed.

Post Installing the node via nvm in Zsh I observed the following things.

1. Paths for the node, nvm, npm & npx have been automatically added to the $PATH variable
2. Node directory is not available neither in `C:\Users\Program Files\nodejs`
   nor the  `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\nvm`
3. Instead it is configured differently at `/home/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node`

This video really helped me in re-installing the node in ZSH: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL8iGErULiw

Answer (score 0):

just add nvm or node in your plugins:

```
plugins=(git nvm)
```

reboot ur terminal. Then, good to go

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).